# Word macro to split document is creating an extra page

Tags: vba, ms-word

I created a macro which, based on user input, splits the Word document into smaller documents and then outputs them as a .pdf with a unique name. Each individual document though is outputting with an extra blank page on the back, which at no point is in the original document. Is there any way to stop this happening/remove the back page before saving to .pdf? I tried removing the final page by section break but that also didn't work.

```
Sub SplitToPDF()

    Dim docMultiple As Document
    Dim docSingle As Document
    Dim rngPage As Range
    Dim iCurrentPage As Integer
    Dim iPageCount As Integer
    Dim strNewFileName As String
    Dim fDialog As FileDialog
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim Response As VbMsgBoxResult
    Dim userInput As Integer
    Dim fso
    Dim currentDate As String
    Dim customerName As String
    Dim currentMonth As String
    Dim currentYear As Integer
        
    Response = MsgBox("Insturctions for use:" & vbNewLine & "Please ensure the first blank page has been deleted." & vbNewLine & "Please ensure you have saved (and re-named) this document to the fund operation name." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "This will also overwrite any other split you have done in the same folder. Continue?", vbExclamation + vbYesNo, "Warning!")
    If Response = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    
    inputData = InputBox("Please enter the length of each letter below.", "Notice length:")
    If inputData = "" Then Exit Sub
    
    '   1 Create dialog for saving and get directory details
    Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fDialog
        .Title = "Select folder to save split files"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
        If .Show <> -1 Then
            MsgBox "Cancelled By User", vbInformation
            Exit Sub
        End If
        DocDir = fDialog.SelectedItems.Item(1)
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Set docMultiple = ActiveDocument
    Set rngPage = docMultiple.Range
    iCurrentPage = 1
    iPageCount = docMultiple.BuiltInDocumentProperties(wdPropertyPages)
    
    '   2 Loop through each page set and copy/paste data
    Do Until iCurrentPage > iPageCount
        If iCurrentPage = iPageCount Then
            rngPage.End = ActiveDocument.Range.End
        Else
            Selection.GoTo wdGoToPage, wdGoToAbsolute, iCurrentPage + inputData
            rngPage.End = Selection.Start
        End If
        
        rngPage.Copy
        Set docSingle = Documents.Add
        docSingle.Range.Paste
        
        For i = 0 To docSingle.Sections.Count
        Next
    
        Set delSec = docSingle.Sections(i)
        delSec.Range.Delete
        
    '   3 Variable for document name
        Application.Selection.Find.Execute "customer: "
        Application.Selection.Expand wdLine
        customerName = Replace(Application.Selection.Text, "customer: ", "")
        x = Len(customerName) - 1
        customerName = Left(customerName, x)
        
        Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        
        currentDate = Replace(Date, "/", "-")
        currentMonth = Format(currentDate, "MMM")
        currentYear = Format(currentDate, "YY")
        currentDate = currentMonth & "_" & currentYear
        
        strNewFileName = fso.GetBaseName(docMultiple) & "_" & currentDate & "_" & customerName & ".pdf"
        docSingle.SaveAs FileName:=DocDir & "\" & strNewFileName, FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF
        
        iCurrentPage = iCurrentPage + inputData
        
        docSingle.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
        rngPage.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    Loop
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Complete", vbInformation
    
    Set docMultiple = Nothing
    Set docSingle = Nothing
    Set rngPage = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: can you show the whole of your code?

Comment: it is not valid code for sure, there are some obvious errors which you should improve first. You should also explain what is in fact 'user input' and how it refers to 'splitting' process.

Answer (score 0):

In Step 2 (Looping through the page sets), just after you do the paste (line 57) add the following:

```
    ' There is now an empty page at the end of the document.
    ' This is caused by a section break. Get rid of it.
    Selection.MoveLeft
    Selection.Delete
```

Remove the extra code looping through the sections.